# Does Rails 2.3 and Rails 3.0 handle the displaying of arrays differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am going through a video tutorial that was using Rails 2.3, and they did:

```
<%= first_array = ['a', 'b', 'c'] %>
```

When they did that, the output they got was:

```
abc
```

When I am trying to follow along, on my setup (Rails 3.0), I get:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Is this difference normal or did I do something incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails doesn't display arrays differently between 2 and 3. But between ruby 1.8 and 1.9 it has changed.

In [ruby 1.8 `to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002152) returns `self.join` which joins all of the elements together without a separator.
In [ruby 1.9 `to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000489) is an alias for `inspect` which returns the array as `"[#{self.join(', ')}]"` (roughty speaking).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I would guess this is a difference between versions of ruby rather than differences between versions of rails.

Comment: Ahh I see. Interesting. You could be right, but would love confirmation :)

Comment: Samuel provided a great explanation for this so please accept his answer :)